# Passing an url from python to JavaScript in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, url, flask

I have this flask app

```
@app.route('', methods=['POST'])
def my_function():
 (...some functions...)
 map = some_url    
 return render_template ("main.html", map = map)
```

And I want to insert "map" into my JavaScript (.js is in /static):

```
 btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var newMap = document.createElement("IMG");     
   newMap.setAttribute("src", "{{map}}");
   newMap.setAttribute("width", "300");
   newMap.setAttribute("height", "300");
```

I do a `print(map)` before `return render_template` and it prints well but `newMap` is created but empty, like with no `src`.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question, which assumes you are using jinja for template rendering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178426/how-can-i-pass-data-from-flask-to-javascript-in-a-template

Comment: @Jon, I already went through this post but when I use a `{{ variable }}` it raises a SyntaxError in my JavaScript console.

Comment: Check this out. If the javascript is in /static it is not a template, and jinja won't render it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335633/import-javascript-files-with-jinja-from-static-folder

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate solution which will work fine.
You can create a hidden input and set its value to the map variable

```
<input type="hidden" value={{map}} id="inputId"/>
```

Now using javascript access the value and change setAtrribute second parmaeter to mapValue

```
mapValue = document.getElementById("inputId").value
newMap.setAttribute("src", mapValue);
```