# Python Flask: How to include JavaScript file for each template per blueprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have read [Loading external script with jinja2 template directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412275/loading-external-script-with-jinja2-template-directive) and [Import javascript files with jinja from static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335633/import-javascript-files-with-jinja-from-static-folder) but unfortunately no closer

I have a Python Flask site which is based on https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-blueprints/ so each blueprint has its own static and templates folder

My question is how would I include a JS file within a block that sits within a static/js folder of the blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to set a separate `static_url_path` for each blueprint unless a `url_prefix` is defined. This adds a prefix to the URL where the static files will be loaded.

```
bp = Blueprint(
    'home', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static',
    static_url_path = '/home/static'
)

# ...
```

```
bp = Blueprint(
    'products', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static',
    url_prefix = '/products',
)

# ...
```

With the help of the `request` object, the name of the current blueprint can be determined. This can then be used to load the static file. Thus, a different file is loaded for each blueprint.

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script src="{{ url_for(request.blueprint+'.static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

It is therefore necessary to adapt both the `template_url_path` or `url_prefix` and the identifier within `url_for` to the requirements.